# duplicate variable in url rewrite with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a product page :

```
product.php
```

this page gets some GET requests .

1.product brand 
2.product series of that brand

with click on brand , it will show that brand of the product :

```
product.php?brand=A
```

I've rewrite it with this command in htaccss :

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) product.php?brand=$1 [NC]
```

and the url is :

```
product/A
```

. so far so good. but here is my problem . I wanna show only one specific series of this brand , normally it works with this :

```
product.php?brand=A&series=a1
```

. but when I use this line in htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) product.php?brand=$1&series=$2 [NC]
```

it doesn't work cause we encounter a duplication : brand=$1 used twice in 2 lines . I can't delete any of these 2 lines cause I need'em . so does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9A-Z]+)/?$ product.php?brand=$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9A-Z]+)/([0-9A-Z]+)/?$ product.php?brand=$1&series=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: it doesn't work , I have " Object not found  " error with this

Comment: It's a problem in your php code, not in this htaccess code.